# Postfix smtpd and smtp restrictions (client, sender, recipient) first restriction that matches wins very ILLOGICAL for brute force attacks

Tags: postfix, sasl, brute-force-attacks

if I have a list of restrictions for:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_rhsbl_helo dbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rhsbl_reverse_client dbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rhsbl_sender dbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
    reject
```

postfix says the first restriction that matches wins. This means a hacker who's trying to brute force my SASL credentials is not in my local network or their IP isnt whitelisted in my config files, according to the rule above, the first restriction will not pass.

They will then try to guess my SASL credentials (the second restriction) and if they get lucky, this restriction wins, and all subsequent restrictions (reject.... etc.) will not apply.

How stupid and illogical is that?

Why would postfix do such a terrible thing? There is a reason why hardening security comes with fail switch multi-layers to further mitigate the damage, severity, and coverage of the attack. This restriction parameter should be conditioned as an **AND** not **OR** statements. In other words, the spammer would have to PASS ALL not ONE restrictions before they connect to my postfix server.

**How can I be able to accomplish this?**

Basically, I want to make it virtually impossible for the spammer to connect via SASL like two factor authentication. So the spammer would have to pass 10+ restrictions to be accepted.

For example, say the hacker is in my mynetworks. This restriction will pass, so rather than postfix ignoring the other restrictions, the hacker would then need to pass SASL authentication. If it passes, he would then need to pass the reject_rhsbl_helo dbl.spamhaus.org restriction (so on an so forth).

**Can this be done? If not, other than using fail2ban since it is a bandaid, how can I effectively and aggressively block brute force SASL attacks as I see numerous entries in my mail.log file?**

Comment: *Brute force* should not be a concern, at all. Either your auth is safe from guessing, or it should not be exposed to the internet anyway. In any case, whether it is exposed to most of the internet or all of the internet does not fundamentally change things.

Comment: Really? How can you say that when all I see in my mail logs is warning: unknown[92.118.38.56]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed. Even this blog mentions it https://www.linuxbabe.com/security/secure-email-server-against-hacking.

Your auth is never safe from guessing. It is not exposed to the Internet but hackers still find a way.

Comment: Your auth is safe from guessing if it makes use of the impracticability of searching exponential space in linear time. After a certain threshold.. such job cannot be finished. Even if you guessed until the last starlight in the universe, or until the IP version transition, whichever comes first.

Comment: ok but I should still have smtpd_client_restrictions just not overkill right? My postfix does not accept incoming messages. It is a SEND ONLY SMTP

Answer (score 1):

#### Understand the threat models

Spammers do not try to bruteforce password logins, as incoming mail should not require a password; the legitimate senders would not have credentials for your mail server, either. If someone was trying to bruteforce credentials for your email server the goal would either be stealing information from the mailboxes or using your server for spamming others, but never sending spam to your users.

Inbound mail could be authenticated using DMARC+DKIM or DMARC+SPF for whether the sender is allowed to use the domain. However, those technologies are for fighting email spoofing rather than spam; spammers can set them up, too.

On the other hand, SASL authentication is for the *submission* i.e. for authenticating outbound mail from your users. You implicitly trust your users and won't expect them to use the system for sending spam. If you didn't, you could have put some `reject_*` rules *before* the `permit_*` rules:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions =
    reject_rhsbl_helo dbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rhsbl_reverse_client dbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rhsbl_sender dbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject
```

Likewise, you could remove the `permit_mynetworks` in this *zero trust* scenario where you expect that someone is already in your network. Then, SASL authentication would be required for everyone regardless of where they connect from.

Once you understand the risks you are trying to handle with the configuration it becomes clear that you can sufficiently achieve that by the simple "first rule wins" logic.

#### Better configuration with the Postfix's multi-instance architecture

Rather than having a single list of restrictions you should split them into two different logics altogether:

- one for inbound mail permitting every mail that does not violate the restrictions like the blocklists:

  ```
  smtpd_client_restrictions = 
      reject_rhsbl_helo dbl.spamhaus.org,
      reject_rhsbl_reverse_client dbl.spamhaus.org,
      reject_rhsbl_sender dbl.spamhaus.org,
      reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
      permit
  ```
- another requiring SASL authentication for the submission:

  ```
  smtpd_client_restrictions =
      permit_sasl_authenticated,
      reject
  ```

The latter is typically configured via `master.cf` having a slightly different syntax, e.g.,

```
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

This configures a separate `smtpd` instance listening on port `465` for *submission**s***, i.e., submission over implicit TLS as defined in [RFC 8314, 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8314.html#section-3.3). The parameters defined with `-o` override the parameters defined in `main.cf` (see [master(5)](https://www.postfix.org/master.5.html)). The Postfix [architecture](https://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html) allows [multiple instances](https://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html) like this. You should be more familiar with the architecture before criticizing it.

Comment: someone can technically brute force their way in because if that wasnt the case neither I nor linuxbabe would be receiving the SASL Login Authentication failed entries: https://www.linuxbabe.com/security/secure-email-server-against-hacking.

Secondly, I am not using my mail server to accept messages. That's for my Namecheap mailbox. My postfix is only sending mail OUT using Mailwizz (client.

You say it's better to include smtpd_client_ restrictions in the master file. I have seen it both ways another reason why I hate postfix docs. There isnt much specificity/clarity or many use cases

Comment: If I decide to include smtpd_client_restrictions in the master file, how would I be able to break it up into two different logics like you listed above in the main.cf? Also what about smtpd_recipient_restrictions and smtpd_sender_restrictions and the smtp variant of that? Should I also include those in the master.cf file if at one point they become relevant?

Comment: As a point of clarification, I am the only user sending email from postfix and only one SASL credential (ME). Given my use case, what do you think would be the best way to structure the smtpd_client_restrictions given the fact there has been already some SASL authentication failed login attempts made on my server. Thoughtful note, my credentials were never made public. These entries you see are most likely from a hacker trying to guess my hostname, port, username, and password in his/her email client. Maybe they found my hostname/IP which is why those failed login entries are being recorded.

Comment: That's most likely Internet's background noise i.e. non-targeted password list attacks & such. If you have a strong password used only for this service, you'll be fine. Of course you could use Fail2Ban, but those attacks often run on botnets with many rotating IP addresses to circumvent Fail2Ban thresholds.

Comment: Common practice is to use main.cf defaults for incoming mail and override the settings on the submission instance. Personally I put almost all the restrictions to `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` as it is evaluated only after full `HELO`, `MAIL FROM` & `RCPT TO` giving better logs for debugging (who tried to send mail to whom).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join a restriction that can net either no match or a rejection, and another restriction that can net either no match or a permit result, in the same class.. just put the permit one last. Then both entries need to be examined to reach the permit result.

*and* and *or* are useful to express boolean logic: where variables and outcomes have only two possible values.

But that is not what is happening in postfix restriction classes, those actually end up with 3 possible results permit/defer/reject, plus a few variants and side effects such as bcc/discard/warn.

Your postfix documentation has a section called [`SMTPD_ACCESS_README`](https://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html) and the specifics of the check_*_access are described in [`man 5 access`](https://www.postfix.org/access.5.html)

Comment: So you are telling me if I add permit at the end instead of reject and have 5 restrictions within smtpd_client_restrictions, all 5 restrictions need to be satisfied to permit SASL login?

If yes, given my use case (See my comments above to Esa), do you think this setup is good or should I just keep it set to the default as in "permit_sasl_authenticated, reject"